# Querying last 5 years

Tags: sql, database, oracle, time

I want to query all products sold in the last 5 years.
It is possible to do it like this:

```
select * from products
where time between sysdate-1826 and sysdate
```

But it there also a nicer way instead of calculating all the days and subtract it from `sysdate`?

Comment: This is indirectly addressed by @JustinCave's answer, but 1826 days does not consistently equal 5 years (a 5 year span can contain 1 or 2 leap years). That's why it's better to use operators that deal in whole months or years (which are consistent).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM products
 WHERE date_column >= add_months( sysdate, -12*5 )
```

or

```
SELECT *
  FROM products
 WHERE date_column >= sysdate - interval '5' year
```

will both give you all the rows from the last 5 years (though you would generally want to add a `TRUNC` to remove the time portion unless you really care whether a row was created on Feb 8, 2007 in the morning or in the afternoon).

Comment: Note regarding the second example: the interval arithmetic will raise  "ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified" if sysdate happens to be a leap day.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from products
where time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 YEAR)
```

Date sub will subtract 5 years from now

Comment: @James L - DATE_SUB is not a function that is available in Oracle.  I believe it's a SQL Server function.

Comment: Thanks, but I was getting the following error `missing right parenthesis`. Then I found this: [date_sub() giving error](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2171098) and this was the solution: `where time > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '5' YEAR`